# mysql как база данных сообщений мессенджера

Tags: php, mysql

Архитектура мессенджера подразумевает, что переписка хранится в БД. Как я понимаю, при этом при инициализации новой переписки динамически создается таблица, которая будет хранить сообщения обоих пользователей. Таблица будет создана, когда пользователь отправит свое первое сообщение. Как динамически создать название этой таблицы, чтобы к ней был доступ со стороны обоих пользователей? Это будет хэш, состоящий из комбинации их id, или есть более практичные средства?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Более практично - не создавать вообще никаких лишних таблиц. А хранить в одной как-то так (упрощённо): текст, id отправителя, id получателя, время.

Comment: 1. Если я Отправитель, то для моего собеседника  я буду Получателем. 
2. Для тысячи пользователей с их личными блоками переписок не будет ли тесно в одной таблице?

Comment: 1) направление передачи всегда однозначно, какие проблемы тут могут быть?
2) размножать таблицы - будет ещё тесней.

Comment: Если у меня ид=100,а у второго юзера 101, то когда я пишу ему, в таблице будет примерно следующее 100 -- 101 --- 2013-01-12 23:20
Когда он пишет мне :   101 -- 100 --- 2013-01-12 23:33
Что-то я не представляю технически как сделать выборку всех наших сообщений из огромной таблицы в хронологическом порядке, учитывая и то, на многие мои сообщения и вовсе  и не было ответа.

Comment: Например, так:

    select * from `messages` where `from_id` in(100,101) and `to_id` in(100,101) order by `sent`

Comment: На вопрос был дан ответ, спасибо, Klopp, тем более, что практически всегда вы первый, кто попадается на мои вопросы. Я вот думаю, может лучше пойти учиться на маляра-штукатура? ))

Comment: Вам бы книги почитать - много и разных. И освоить великую технику "обратный инжиниринг" - это когда вы берете готовое решение (маленькое, простое, некрасивое, но рабочее) и пытаетесь понять, как оно сделано.

Comment: @SilverIce, ответ прибился, что ли? С выдачей всё просто: история может хранится и локально, независимо от сброса на сервер. Её куда проще показывать, а для глубокого копания в полной истории делается отдельный интерфейс.

Comment: А да. мноюприбился)... мне показалось неинтересно развивать тему. 

С выдачей - это для вас просто). А задавшему вопрос пока нужно разобраться хотя бы технических деталях SQL-отборов. А тут нужно придумать механизм, по которому будут отбираться актуальные данные для выдачи в СОМЕТ-запрос; не самая очевидная задача))

Comment: Если честно, задача вообще может рассматриваться как исключительно для самообразования :) Потому как на практике в over9000 случаев проще поднять свой jabber...